# Is Drupal project supposed to be empty?

Tags: drupal, installation, customization, customizing

I was given a Drupal project and asked to figure out how its code base structured and how the project is structured overall.

I successfully installed it using xampp.

Now I see nothing custom in the project:

[image]

For blocks I have only `Bartik` and `Rubik`. For content type only `Basic page`. For file types `Audio`, `Document`, `Image` and `Video`. For menus `Main Menu`, `Management`, `Navigation` and `User menu`.

So, does it mean that I was given a blank empty project? What else may I check that may have been customly changed in an empty project? What may I have missed while installing the project that may cause it to become empty, without any customisations? Maybe it is possible to check for something in the files of the project?

I am asking a few questions here, since I am not sure which one of them will convey the matter which concerns me. But basically all of them mean the same: I just want to see what someone else did in the project. And the more customisations I will find, the better it will be.

Thank you.

Comment: What "custom" stuff do you expect to see? The image you posted is what I would expect after installing drupal

Comment: @2pha, (1) according to [this](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/before-you-start/2008-09-28/how-to-preview-my-website) in Drupal you are always in preview mode. (2) As I wrote at the beginning `I was given a Drupal project and asked to figure out how its code base structured and how the project is structured overall.`. Having (1) and (2) would you expect someone to send me an empty Drupal project? No, I was told that the project is not empty. Thank you.

Comment: Wow, lose the attitude mate

Comment: @2pha, what does it mean?

Comment: When you visited site for the first time locally did Drupal gave you form typical for site setup (i.e. to enter master admin info and stuff)?

Comment: @MilanG, I was presented with the ordinary Drupal setup.

Comment: That means that Drupal didn't find your database. Did you migrate database at all? If so, then something is wrong in your sites/default/settings.php file. Most likely you didn't provide new database user credentials there. Drupal is offering setup page when he can not find existing database.

Comment: @MilanG, yes, I did not migrate db at all. I am suspecting that is the issue here. I requested the db from those who provided me with the project. They did not answer yet. Thank you.

Comment: Well, site will hardly work without the database. :) Hint - check out if maybe "backup&migrate" module is installed. If so you can get DB dump on your own. Or maybe you can install that module your self.

Comment: @MilanG, how could I check that the `backup&migrate` module is installed?

Comment: Login as admin to working (live?) site and go to Configuration -> System. If B&M is installed it should be visible there. If not, go to Modules and try installing it form there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does look like a virgin install typically does. If you were expecting to see more, perhaps you need to import a database...

1. Confirm you've imported the project database and that your settings file is pointing to it. It looks like you're using Drupal 8, so the file should be in `sites/default/settings.php`
2. Check under Content to see if any nodes have been created. If you have some sort of botched import, you can also try accessing a few nodes randomly at `example.com/node/1`, `example.com/node/2` to check directly in case something is wrong with the index
3. Other than Nodes, Drupal content can be also in the form of Views. These are available at `example.com/admin/structure/views`. This is usually for heavily customised content. There are roughly 15 default Views that come with Drupal 8.
4. A default install will have no Modules installed in `/modules`. If you're seeing any directories there, it could be that the site was relying on these to display the content you're being asked to admin.

Trust this puts you on the right path. :)

Comment: Thank you, but it seems I cannot try out your solutions. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53898557/cannot-login-to-drupal-admin-or-reset-password) is the issue I am getting into. Thank you.

Comment: I am just curious what do you mean by `heavily customized`? Do you mean that it is customized a lot or do you mean that it is hard to customize it? I am almost sure that you meant the former, but I am asking just in case. Thank you.

Comment: If I want to change a db for my project in Drupal, then will just changing the respective entry in `sites/default/settings.php` help me to do that? Or should I reinstall the project from scratch or maybe do something else in addition to updating the entry in `sites/default/settings.php`?

Comment: Views allow content to completely break out of the limitations of a template - in other words, and, to reuse your wording: heavily customised. Essentially custom content that can consist of blocks, PHP, jQuery and any other methods you can think of displaying content, in ways that might exceed the limitations of nodes.